# ThreeJS: create smoothed terrain from set of verticies

Tags: three.js, triangulation, terrain

I have a set of XYZ coordinates that I want to draw a smoothed 'terrain'-like mesh overtop of.   I want it have smoothed (like hills instead of sharp mountains) like from a Bézier curve.

How can i connect the verticies so it forms a terrain texture when viewed from directly above?  (there will never be 'caves')

Comment: Hard to know exactly what you want from your description, but maybe the [subdivision modifier](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_modifier_subdivision) is what you want

Comment: Did you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19905637/normal-averaging-of-heightmap